# What can I do with my unwanted items?

Tags: resident-evil-6

Is there anything useful I can do with my unwanted items other than to dispose of them?

I know there appear to be no concept of money like in RE4 and RE5 but can I exchange them for skills points somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items can only be shared in split-screen. In all other modes, items can only be trashed once your character picks them up—not traded, dropped, or cashed in. The function of trashing is to make more space in your inventory, and once it's gone, it's gone forever. Co-op drops are separate and unique, so you can't even save "your" herb for your partner (or vice versa).